# Creating a valid date from invalid input such as 2012-02-31

Tags: php, datetime

Is there a way To force php create a DateTime object with an invalid argument such as "2012-02-31", without changing it to 2012-03-02 or somthing like that?

Comment: I think you are looking in the wrong direction. Why do you need to do this in the first place?

Comment: @DainisAbols has a good point. You should be rejecting invalid values. If an invalid date such as "2012-02-31" is given then how can you say that it should be "2012-03-21"?

Comment: Ok, I wnat my user be albe to enter dates like '1391-02-31' and it is real date in persian calendar. actually I want to consider it a persian date.

Comment: That makes more sense. I think that you will have many problems using DateTime for that as it is based on Gregorian dates. Would something like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28380/Persian-Calendar-in-PHP help? I don't know if its maintained, but it may get you started.

Comment: Or this one http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4852-PHP-Convert-and-format-dates-of-the-Persian-calendar.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
try {
    $date = new DateTime('2012-02-31'); // constuct with "impossible date"
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // result: 2012-03-02
?>
```

creating a `DateTime`-object with an "impossible date" isn't a problem (but it's turned into a "real" date on output). [see it working on codepad](http://codepad.org/Gt41dWjU).